# Undef value assigned to variable.

Tags: perl, undefined

The return value of  5 > 6 is undef. However when I assign the value of 5 > 6 to a variable that variable is defined. How do I pass the value of a statement using a comparison operator that resolves to undef on failure?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict ;
use warnings;
print'Five is more than six ? ',      5 >  6, "\n";
print 'Five is less than six ? ' , 5 < 6 , "\n";
my $wiz = 5 > 6 ;

if (defined($wiz)) {
    print '$wiz is defined' ;
    } else {
    print '$wiz is undefined' ;
}


$ ./lessthan
Five is more than six ?
Five is less than six ? 1
$wiz is defined
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I pass the value of a statement using a comparison operator that resolves to undef on failure?

Generally speaking, Perl doesn't promise to return any specific true or false value from its operators, and `<` is no exception. If you want specific values, you will need something like

```
$boolean ? $value_for_true : $value_for_false
```

so

```
my $wiz = 5 > 6 ? 1 : undef;
```

If you only care about the value you get for false, you could also use the following:

```
my $wiz = 5 > 6 || undef;
```

The two options turn out to be equivalent, but this isn't guaranteed.

---

> The return value of 5 > 6 is undef. However when I assign the value of 5 > 6 to a variable

That's not true. The variable is assigned a defined value because `5 > 6` evaluated to a defined value. While Perl doesn't specify what false value it returns from it's operators, it usually returns the scalar `sv_no`, which is a dualvar that appears to be an empty string when treated as a string, and zero when treated as a number.

```
$ perl -wE'say "> ", "".( undef )'
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at -e line 1.
>

$ perl -wE'say "> ", "".( "" )'
>

$ perl -wE'say "> ", "".( 0 )'
> 0

$ perl -wE'say "> ", "".( 5>6 )'
>                                     # Behaves as ""
```

```
$ perl -wE'say "> ", 0+( undef )'
Use of uninitialized value in addition (+) at -e line 1.
> 0

$ perl -wE'say "> ", 0+( "" )'
Argument "" isn't numeric in addition (+) at -e line 1.
> 0

$ perl -wE'say "> ", 0+( 0 )'
> 0

$ perl -wE'say "> ", 0+( 5>6 )'
> 0                                   # Behaves as 0
```

Answer (score 4):

`5 > 6` is not undefined, but it is a false value. In this case, a `dualvar` that acts like an empty string when used as a string, or `0` when used as a number.

Because the value is false, you can just do

```
if ( $wiz ) { ... }
```

If you really want `$wiz` to be undefined, you could do something like this.

```
my $wiz = 5 > 6 || undef;
```

Now, if the expression `5 > 6` is true, `$wiz` will be `1`, otherwise it will be `undef`.

Comment: It's not the empty string, it's a dualvar. It acts like the empty string when used as a string, and zero when used as a number. See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Truth-and-Falsehood and http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Relational-Operators

Comment: So the less than or greater than operator resolves to 1 on successful and "falsey' on fail, which is an empty string, and not undef.

Comment: I just see that the result off 5 > 6 is nothing, or undef. So if I assign the result of 5 > 6 to the variable, you would think that the result of 5 > 6, which does not seem defined, would get assigned to the variable . However by assigning that to the variable - you define it.

Comment: Casper, the expression `5 > 6` is  not nothing (or `undef`) but instead a **defined** falsey value. Try this ternary to see: `print defined(5 > 6) ? 'def' : 'undef'`

Answer (score -1):

Boolean false and undef are two different things ...

comparison assignments are executed in Boolean context only returning boolean values only and undef is not boolean thing
chk this

```
if(defined false){
    print "false is also defined thing.."
}else{
    print "else .."
}
```

So back to question , seems like comparisons can't return undef